# When I load an image from gallery in my android application, why does the bitmap return a smaller image?

Tags: android-camera, android-imageview, android-bitmap, android-gallery

I am capturing an image from the camera of an android phone and saving it in the gallery. When I am loading the image from the gallery, the resultant image is always smaller than the original image. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Picture in gallery is:

[image: picture loaded from gallery]

The picture inside the android application when loaded from the gallery is:

[image: image loaded from gallery]

I am using the following code to load the image into the imageView:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    final Bitmap capturedimage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri, options);
    BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), capturedimage1);
    //capturedImg is the imageView and capturedimage1 is the bitmap image loaded from gallery
    capturedImg.setImageBitmap(capturedimage1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Becasue you choose [inSampleSize=2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize).

Comment: when I did not use inSampleSize=2, I got the same result

Comment: How is your **capturedImg** declared in layout XML? Specifically, do you set `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` ?

Comment: No, I am simply using an imageView inside a linear layout. The orientation of the layout is vertical. The gravity of the imageView is center and (adjustViewBounds=true)